# What kind of graph is this and how can we create it? Is this something we can do in Python?

Tags: animation, plot, graph

I've seen this graph with animation a few times, but I don't know what it's called or how to create it. Can anyone help?

Here's a sample video: https://youtu.be/UkhLvJ6RSKc

Haven't tried much because I don't know what this is called.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer. It's called a "bar race chart"